# Как разместить миниатюры слева и справа?

Tags: html, css

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать так, чтоб миниатюрки фото стояли как справа, так и слева. Вот код.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Фотогалерея с помощью CSS</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:50px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#FFF;
    background:#000;
}
a img{border:none;}

#gallery2{
    width:663px;
    height:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    margin:0 auto 100px auto;
}
#tabs2{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:130px;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
}
#tabs2 li{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
}
#tabs2 li a img{
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    height:90px;
}
#tabs2 li a{
    display:block;
    border:5px solid #fff;
    width:120px;
    height:90px;
}
#fullPicBlock{
    width:533px;
    height:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    background:#242424;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Галерея №2. Переключение картинок на click.</h1>
<div id="gallery2">
    <ul id="tabs2">
        <li><a href="#pic1"><img src="images/pic1s.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#pic2"><img src="images/pic2s.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#pic3"><img src="images/pic3s.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#pic4"><img src="images/pic4s.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fullPicBlock">
        <div><a name="pic1"></a><img src="images/pic1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        <div><a name="pic2"></a><img src="images/pic2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        <div><a name="pic3"></a><img src="images/pic3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        <div><a name="pic4"></a><img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Приведите адрес в интернете, где это находится.

Comment: http://html-css.info/uploads/gallerycss/
Вот сайт пример

Comment: А что именно у Вас не выходит?

Comment: Миниатюрки только слева, их 4 штуки. Мне нужно чтоб они были и слева и справа. Вместе 8 фоток

Answer (score 2):

Так в чем проблема? Добавьте еще один список.

```
<div id="gallery2">
    <ul id="tabs2">
        <li><a href="#pic1"><img src="images/pic1s.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#pic2"><img src="images/pic2s.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#pic3"><img src="images/pic3s.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#pic4"><img src="images/pic4s.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
     <ul id="tabs1">
        <li><a href="#pic1"><img src="images/pic1s.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#pic2"><img src="images/pic2s.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#pic3"><img src="images/pic3s.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#pic4"><img src="images/pic4s.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fullPicBlock">
        <div><a name="pic1"></a><img src="images/pic1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        <div><a name="pic2"></a><img src="images/pic2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        <div><a name="pic3"></a><img src="images/pic3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        <div><a name="pic4"></a><img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

И Css

```
#tabs1{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:130px;
    height:400px;
    float:right;
}
#tabs1 li{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:right;
}
#tabs1 li a img{
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    height:90px;
}
#tabs1 li a{
    display:block;
    border:5px solid #fff;
    width:120px;
    height:90px;
}
```

Comment: Изменил, исчезло все. Наверное проблемы с размером. Не можешь пожалуйста помочь все поменять? буду очень благодарен

Comment: Все вышло. Спасибо огромное!!!!

Comment: @илья, если ответ Вам помог, отметьте его, поставив галочку слева от ответа.